# How to plot the number of observations with time intervals dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, intervals

I have data with id, start time, and end time.

```
ID              start_time                end_time 
1          2017-12-29 03:52:06      2017-12-29 04:56:00
2          2017-12-29 04:12:34      2017-12-29 04:44:00
3          2017-12-29 04:24:36      2017-12-29 05:26:00
4          2017-12-29 04:30:00      2017-12-29 06:24:00
5          2017-12-29 04:33:28      2017-12-29 06:00:00
6          2017-12-29 04:52:08      2017-12-29 06:07:00
7          2017-12-29 05:13:48      2017-12-29 06:33:00
8          2017-12-29 05:33:53      2017-12-29 06:39:00
9          2017-12-29 05:40:00      2017-12-29 07:15:00
10         2017-12-29 05:30:40      2017-12-29 07:00:00
11         2017-12-29 06:08:15      2017-12-29 07:31:00
12         2017-12-29 06:12:33      2017-12-29 07:25:00
```

If I plot these time intervals, it looks like as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(time_day1) + 
  aes(x = start_time, xend = end_time, y = id, yend=id, colour = id) + 
  geom_segment() + 
  geom_point() + geom_point(aes(x = end_time )) + 
  xlab("Time") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

what I would like to plot is the series of the number of observations(ids) with the same x-axis (time) as a time-series plot. I'd appreciate if you provide the appropriate approach for this.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it was the solution to your problem or give further information if it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your post, so that the variables in the data and function match.

To change the appearance of the x-axes, you can use `scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d.%m.%Y")`. In this case the colums start_time/first_time and end_time/last_time have to be of class `POSIXct`.

To read more about it see the [R Graph Gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/279-plotting-time-series-with-ggplot2.html) or the official reference of the [tidyverse/ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) packages.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It was slightly different from what I asked, but it was helpful and I solved the issue! Thank you !!